# Stopping and Starting an task

Tags: c, scheduler, freertos

So. It is an abstract question.
While learning about FreeRTOS I got stuck in some problems.

As an background, I tried to blink a led from a function, and it blinks regarding if it is inside for(;;) or outside, which somewhat is not adding up with the fact that a task is running only inside for(;;) loop after initialization/first run through it.

Trying to be as clear as posible:

> Task functions should never return so are typically implemented as a continuous loop.

An task is defined as:

```
void vATaskFunction( void *pvParameters )
{
    for( ;; )
    {
        -- Task application code here. --
    }

    /* Tasks must not attempt to return from their implementing
    function or otherwise exit.  In newer FreeRTOS port
    attempting to do so will result in an configASSERT() being
    called if it is defined.  If it is necessary for a task to
    exit then have the task call vTaskDelete( NULL ) to ensure
    its exit is clean. */
    vTaskDelete( NULL );
}
```

Knowing that, my question is:

- If a task is an infinite loop, how does the scheduler suspends it (switch to another task)?
- What happens to current values inside the local variables?
- While switching back to our task, does the task jumps directly inside the for(;;) loop, or goes normally through the function, as normal?

Comment: Google "**preemptive multitasking**". From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRTOS#Key_features): *"Scheduler can be configured for both preemptive or cooperative operation."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tasks have their own stacks so the local variables values are retained.

RTOSes work completely different way than the "normal" OS-es.

If there is only one task with the highest priority (and many others with the lower priorities) it has to give the control back to the system. It happens when the task enters the Suspended or Blocked state. Otherwise it will **never** be preempted. (Of course the interrupts will be triggered).

As an example: if you start tasks **A** and **B** an the priority of the task **A** is higher then **B** if the task **A** will not give control back to the system by entering the Suspended or Blocked state (for example by waiting for the notification, semaphore, mutex or something else) the task **A** will have 100% of the execution time and the task **B** 0% (zero)

If there are more than one task with the same highest priority the round robin preemption will happen. It is anyway very uncommon situation in the embedded RTOS development.

Comment: Great. One more thing, how does the alocation of variables before loop affects the for loop, when scheduler "restart" the task? Thanks

Comment: it does not matter. it is just normal function. Standard C rules.

Comment: Does that mean that I am overriding the values of the variable that was saved before task switching?

Comment: No because you never exit the function. The task is all the time the same